Running Data Augmentation on VGG16, while not including the non-trainable aspect when fitting the model
I am attempting to do transfer learning on my dataset of 27,000 images of 149 classes using the vgg16 network with pre-trained weights on Imagenet data. I cannot use GPU on my mac and do not have access to any cloud computing platforms, as a result training the vgg16 network is very slow (each epoch taking many hours), even when I freeze the weights in the layers prior to the Flatten layer. My solution to this was to perform the forward propagation on the convolution layers and use the output of this as the input to train a small densely connected network to fit to my images.
This works well other than I overtrain the model dramatically getting an accuracy of 95% and a val accuracy of 65%. I believe the best solution is to use some data augmentation. Usually I would include some layers in my CNN so that the input is different on each epoch. However, since I am running the data through the convolution layers only once to save on training time, this will not effectively augment my data. I have come up with two potential solutions, neither of which I think are ideal:

Augment the data prior to running it through the vgg16 model. I.e. creating a much larger training dataset instead of augmenting the data within the pipeline. My issue here is that the dataset already takes a long time to run on the vgg16 network so if I increase the size of the dataset x3 or x4 it will probably 6 hours to run. I am also struggling with space on my disk saving these large datasets.

Perform data augmentation on the output of the vgg16 model that will input into the trained densely connected model. Logically to me this doesn't make sense since at all but might work theoritically?


Some help would be much appreciated. See my code below:
vgg16 = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(200, 200, 3))

from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

vgg16_scale = models.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape = (200, 200, 3),),
            layers.Rescaling(1.0/255),
]
)
for layer in vgg16.layers[1:]:
    layer.trainable = False
    vgg16_scale.add(layer)

input_ = layers.Input(shape = (6,6,512))
flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()
dense_layer_1 = layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu')
dense_layer_2 = layers.Dense(500, activation='relu')
prediction_layer = layers.Dense(149, activation='softmax')


vgg_trainable = models.Sequential([
    input_,   
    flatten_layer,
    dense_layer_1,
    dense_layer_2,
    prediction_layer
])

vgg_train_output = vgg16_scale.predict(train_ds)
vgg_val_output = vgg16_scale.predict(val_ds)

np.save("vgg_output/vgg_train_output", vgg_train_output)
np.save("vgg_output/vgg_val_output", vgg_val_output)

vgg_train_output = np.load("vgg_output/vgg_train_output.npy")
vgg_val_output = np.load("vgg_output/vgg_val_output.npy" )

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((vgg_train_output, y_train))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((vgg_val_output, y_val))

BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model = vgg_trainable

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', patience=20,  restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=200, validation_data=val_dataset,  callbacks=[early_stop], verbose=True)


The data augmentation I would like looks something like this:
        tf.keras.layers.Resizing(height=120, width=120),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.2, value_range=[0., 1.] ),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal"),
        tf.keras.layers.RandomCrop(height=100, width=100),

